# email not sending in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku

In config/environments/production.rb

```
  BASE_URL = "http://proproots.herokuapp.com/"
  STATIC_WEBSITE = "http://proproots.herokuapp.com/"
  REDIRECTING_URL = "http://proproots.herokuapp.com/"

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'proproots.herokuapp.com' }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => "587",
    :domain               => "www.gmail.com",
    :user_name            => "sample@gmail.com",
    :password             => "password",
    :authentication       => "login",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
  }
```

server log given below

```
2013-12-13T17:33:49.134524+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=proproots.herokuapp.com fwd="122.164.115.170" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=0
```

It is working fine in development environments but not working in Production , Please someone try to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku does **not** need to use a mailer add-on.  I've done this several times without it, however, a mailer is recommended if you want more robust configuration, the ability to have truly whitelisted IPs which ISPs trust, etc.

Here's an example of my `config/initializers/setup_mail.rb` running in production on Heroku:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "example.com",
    :user_name            => "donotreply@example.com",
    :password             => ENV["EMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true 
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com', protocol: 'http' }
```

I think your problem is using "`www.gmail.com`" as your `domain` in the `smtp_settings`...  I'd also remove the `openssl_verify_mode` line.

See [Tom Slykhouse's blog post](http://www.azgaard.com/2012/06/05/sending-email-from-rails-using-smtp-on-heroku/) on this exact topic for more details.  This is where I got the above config from and it's worked great for me for over a year.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your error comes from your favicon.ico file in your path is missing.
Have your tried http://proproots.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico
Remove your link from your layout file or add a favicon.ico to your public directory.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score -1):

On Heroku, you need to use a mailer addon (I like Postmark).

You'll find a complete list, as well as instructions on how to implement them here:

https://addons.heroku.com/#email-sms

Comment: This is not true.  You don't need an add-on to send email.  See: http://www.azgaard.com/2012/06/05/sending-email-from-rails-using-smtp-on-heroku/